# Unbypassable way to block all distracting sites / content on Ubuntu?

Tags: productivity, parental-controls

I struggle with really low productivity due to having ADHD and spending a lot of time on social media. I’ve tried installing extensions to block them but I end up just uninstalling the extensions (poor impulse control)

I’d like to install a strict parental control software or something, which should block all distracting sites, and I shouldn’t be able to bypass it. May be there’s a password to unblock it which I share with a friend , and the password unlocks it for a bit when I’ve finished my work for the day. But then it goes back to blocking everything .

I shouldn’t be able to ‘sudo killall -12’ or equivalent to stop it , if i do then the computer should become unusable until the lock is restored.

May be I need to code something like this myself and bake it into the kernel so it can’t be overridden ? Perhaps a distro like this already exists? Or may be the source code of chromium could be modified to do this? (But then I’d have the option to install another browser. I want this to be out of my hands, and be really really painful to bypass).

Comment: If this is *your* computer and you don't have anyone else who can 'manage' the administrative side of things (thereby disabling your `sudo` access entirely since someone else can assist with actual software installs) then there's no real way to do this.  (Basically, if you are the only controller of the infrastructure and the only one with admin passwords, you've already lost the battle)

Comment: Also, 18.10 is past End of Life, so if you are still using 18.10 you should upgrade it to 19.10.  (Or reinstall 18.04 and then later upgrade to 20.04 once it releases)

Comment: "I want to install something I can't get around."  Sounds impossible to me.

Comment: What are the non real ways? 

Comment: @ClickUpvote there aren't any unless you hand over administration of your laptop to a third party.  Because you yourself are the only one in control of your infrastructure (i.e. it's not 'managed' by anyone else) then only you have `sudo` access.  In a corporate environment for example, only the IT admins have `sudo` power and end users don't get any admin powers (or limited depending on configurations).  This way, they can't do what you do to 'bypass' programs.

Comment: Hm, I could give my sudo password to a friend in order to make this work

Comment: @ClickUpvote They'd need to intervene every time you need to install any piece of software or to run `apt` or package upgrades, etc.  Are you really sure your friend wants to be the sole point of contact for any administration of your system?

Comment: @thomas ward I could hire someone off fiverr or such to do this too. Would be a lot cheaper than the lost productivity..

Comment: The best we can do is to add a 'speed bump' which might help remind you to ask yourself "what's the best use of my time for me right now?"

Comment: @user535733 He said he has ADHD. That means he is fully aware of the problem and has probably already sought and received professional help. That's why he is trying to manage the problem by using tools to control the issue. This is a major challenge faced by millions of people - often highly intelligent, highly creative and skilled people who don't need to be patronized about the seriousness of the implications of what they do.

Comment: @fred2 fair enough. Thanks for helping me to understand better,

Comment: Actually, this is a legit request. For other systems, there are solutions for this (https://focusme.com/, https://freedom.to/, https://getcoldturkey.com/) but not for Linux.

Personally, I found, at least for the web part, LeechBlock to be quite useful. For non-web-based apps, however, I would be happy to see (and even pay) for a working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is: you're the only one with access to your system, and you control it and its administration.  Because of this, you need `sudo` access to access administrative functions.  And as such, you retain the ability to bypass almost anything because of `sudo` commands and access.

The only *true* way to achieve what you're after is to hand off all administrative functions (and therefore 'control' of the system) to a third party other than yourself - that way, they control `sudo` and admin powers, and you can't bypass anything by doing `sudo killall` or similar.

THIS SAID, that person will be the sole admin on your system - once they are given admin powers, you would remove yourself from the `sudo` group and therefore have *no* administrative power on the sytem at all.  So this person has to be ready and available to respond to any cases where you need admin intervention.

(This is actually how corporate environments protect their systems from end-users having local admin on all systems and making changes - without `sudo` they can't really touch the system files or administrative things, and only the IT administrators can.)

Answer (score 7):

I'm writing this while I'm procrastinating from doing something much more important and urgent.

I recently got diagnosed as adult ADHD after a lifetime of dealing with procrastination. Diagnosis, and even medication, is certainly helpful, but doesn't fix the issue without what seems like a continual grind to try to work efficiently, with frequent failures. It's very easy to end every day feeling like you've failed, which means there's never any reward for when you do actually achieve some work.

In case people think ADHD is a condition of people who are dumb or lack self-discipline - I  have a PhD. I've written books which have won national awards. I run a business which has been successful for 15 years. I have achieved a lot by many people's standards.

And I can spend an entire week staring at a computer while getting zero work done. Literally zero. And yet at the end of the week I'm still exhausted from a week-long battle to try to get myself to start whatever job it is I'm meant to be dealing with - but naturally don't feel I can take time off to 'recharge' when I've been doing nothing productive. I can, and have, done this to such an extent that I've risked business, family, everything ...

So I just want to express a lot of sympathy for @ClickUpvote. It's brutal.

From a practical perspective, as has already been said, you can't stop a superuser from being a superuser. But here are some things which I find have helped a bit, and some things which might be worth trying.

You've already tried this, but install something like https://freedom.to/ on your phones and computers and activate in browsers. Yes, you can work around these, but at least you have to consciously disable them. The app for phone is particularly valuable because I've been too lazy to work out how to deactivate it so far. Unfortunately on Ubuntu it's very easy.

Another tool to add to the mix is Toggl time tracker (https://toggl.com/). I really find this helps to 'keep me honest'. You record exactly what work you are doing during the work day, and you feel a reward for actually doing real work. You can see the hours mounting up, and you can't hide from what you've done with your time. It's free to use for basic accounts. You can then share your stats with people you know to 'prove' you've been productive, and again, perhaps get some positive reinforcement.

Not possible right now (April 2020), but I've found working in a public place can help. Go to a library or coffee shop with your laptop rather than always working in the same place. Depends on your work situation - but I'm guessing you don't have a boss peering over your shoulder.

The best fix of all is probably a sympathetic friend or family member who can keep you honest. You don't want someone to nag, but you do want someone who will maybe chase you up, ask whether you've got stuff done, and also encourage you to get some pleasure from progress in the right direction, rather than overnight perfection.

Finally - much bigger question. Is there anything else which is making work hard to achieve. Are you depressed? Are you doing a job you hate? Could you change career direction? A lot of people with ADHD suck at focusing on things they hate, but can 'hyperfocus' on things they are enthusiastic about. I know this is the case with me. I can work faster and harder than anybody when I'm really into the subject. It's routine and drudgery that's seemingly impossible to overcome with a 'just get it done and then it will be over' approach. And today's passion can become tomorrow's drudgery. But finding something you really love doing which also pays the wages is always going to help.

Good luck. I often tell people that 'everything I've learned how to do that has any value I learned when I was meant to be doing something else". My business started as procrastination. A new venture this year started as procrastination. I play the guitar pretty damn well - because of procrastination. So ... if all else fails, find something to procrastinate on that might have some value down the road.

ps. I've had exactly the same thought as you - that's how I found your question. Is there some way I can prevent myself breaking my own rules? Ultimately, you either need to hand sudo power to someone else or find a different solution. That said (I haven't investigated this) you might be able to work out Linux user permissions in such a way that your account has 'almost' admin permissions by controlling which groups you are a member of, but no permissions over the blocking app. That might limit the inconvenience of handing ultimate control to someone else. Maybe a project you can waste some time investigating ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can resists to find out, how bypass the app "control parental".

It is a website blocker **without** a browser plugin, therefore bypassing is much more harder.

https://ubunlog.com/en/ctparental-herramienta-de-control-parental/