# App to stop distractions

Tags: lock, focus

Can someone recommend any app that can be used to help stop distractions and procrastination? I am aware of some applications that exist for writing text which have their own editor window. These range from blacking out everything except the app (=visual fix) to stopping access to all other apps for a set amount of time (=access fix).

What I ask is for something slightly different. If I am using Blendr, I must be able to use the app to
0. Set a particular time window (pomodoro)

1. Only use Blendr
2. Not allow me to access any other apps on my computer

So that for the next ~60 min I can do nothing other than work in Blendr.

Now, replace Blendr with any application: say Gimp, Matlab and so on.

Comment: I must say your use case is quite unclear to me. Work without distractions I can understand (although the desktop, panel etc. will communicate with you anyway), but why on earth would I force myself to use application x for at least (?) y amount of time?

Comment: @JacobVlijm if you're working on a project, and don't have enough self-control to keep yourself from visiting various websites every 5 minutes? TBH I looked for something like this, and I don't remember being able to find one for Linux, especially if you have root (because then you can just turn it off regardless)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unbypassable way to block all distracting sites / content on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213187/unbypassable-way-to-block-all-distracting-sites-content-on-ubuntu)