# How to write an override to prevent an application from launching?

Tags: bash, scripts, launcher, startup, bashrc

I am looking for help to write a script or terminal command by which I can prevent an app from launching. Let us call this script .bash_ban for instance.

Is it possible to write up a command in .bash_ban that prevents Firefox from launching either by

1. through the terminal start command, OR
2. icon click, OR
3. application search bar

I must then be able to disable this .bash_ban from running upon using another command eg. bash_ban_command --disable

Comment: @Nmath See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440091/app-to-stop-distractions for context.

Comment: @Nmath I wrote the other question as @ ChanganAuto commented. I am asking this in parallel, so that if this is possible, I would learn and write/fix a daemon or service that does this - so I can use it as a hacky substitute for a distraction prevention application.